# CodeIgniter Redirect back correct way

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am facing one issue while using CodeIgniter.
Actually I have one form which is opened by calling the controller
(say **http://www.example.com/class1/func1**)

the form is getting submitted to **/class1/func2**
Now the issue is in the case when the form validation error occurs or any db errors occurs, in my controller i just loaded the view again using

$this->load->view()
and it has loaded the form once again, but the url of the browser still remains to **/class1/func2**
To resolve this, i have created my own function which redirects the url to the last page using **redirect()** function , it has solved the issue of url in browser but in that case i am not able to use set_value() instead have to use flashdata session to fill the form values.

Is is the correct way?
Also is there anyway using which i can change the url by using simple $this->load-->view()?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should display your code so we can look at it.

Comment: Yeah as mustang says show some code and we will help. Generally though if the page has to reload then you need to put anything you want to persist in the session (as it sounds like you are). This is the "correct" approach I reckon. Didn't follow the query about changing url at all though